# The <title> of the page is changing. How to get it with XPath?

Tags: xpath, webdriver

Got the page with dynamic `<title>` tag depending on language selected by user, e.g.
`<title>English</title>` or `<title>Italiano</title>`

I'm trying to select that page among many others with XPath selector:

`//*[contains(@title, 'English') or contains(@title, 'Italiano')]`

but it doesn't work at all.

Also tried
`(//*[contains(@title, 'English')] | //*[contains(@title, 'Italiano')])[1]` - no positive result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`title` is not an attribute, so no need to add `@`:

```
//*[contains(title, 'English') or contains(title, 'Italiano')]
```

This will return parent node. If you want to select `title` node then try

```
//title[.='English' or .='Italiano']
```